# EF6 Force in-memory model creation for code-first before data access

Tags: entity-framework

As far as I know for code first the in-memory model is created on the first data access leading to a delay on a first data access (several seconds in my case).

Is there a way to force the in-memory model creation on application start to avoid delay during the first data access?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Attempt to access data trivially, before a user needs it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I do before services start, but this involves bringing the data layer to where it should not be. I thought there could be a cleaner solution. Similar to setting DatabaseInitializer in DBConfiguration class, instead of in, say, main().

Comment: Ah ha; looks like Mark got you in his answer. Now that I see it, I remember I've done this before myself!

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the database by using an EF database initializer and calling the `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>`'s `InitializeDatabase` method.

You can use any of the built-in database initializers to do this.

An example using the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer in the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>());
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }
```

The `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer will check to see if there are any model changes each time your application starts and if there is, it will drop and recreate the database based on the latest model.

You can use one of the following initializers instead of `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`:

CreateDatabaseIfNotExists

DropCreateDatabaseAlways

MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion (if you're using DbMigrations)

Comment: Thanks, but no, I am not asking about initializers! They create a database. But in code-first when you start your application and then try to access the data, during this EF will try to make an in-memory model it will be using to map DBSets to the DB (lazy in memory model creation). This leads to a noticeable delay (but only on the first data access). I was hoping there was a way to make EF make this in-memory model before first data access, eagerly so to say.

Comment: @alexW Database creation is not the only job of the initializer. The __MigrationHistory table in your database is also checked when the database is initialized. __MigrationHistory is a table EF creates in your database to track changes you make to figure out what state your database is in and which migrations to apply. Are you absolutely sure, that the problem is not caused by something else? Perhaps an IIS recycle happening when you launch your app for the first time?

Comment: @alexW I also noticed that you mentioned you don't want to bring the data layer where it shouldn't be (which is great I completely agree with). I usually create a class and a method called .InitializeDatabase() in my services layer, then call the method from application start. That way I don't have to reference my Database layer in my web application.

Comment: No absolutely sure. I make a fake call to data before data real access, then I can access them fine. Otherwise the first call takes quite a while. I remember this from a pluralsite course and why is this: code first does not have edmx so it has to create one lazily in memory. Just doing a fake data call is a hack in same way. And it is run locally via owing